# Angular + ui-angular dynamic tabs with dynamic controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to construct permission based admin dashboard. Header of html consists of some main havs and the last nav is for `Settings`. I use `angular-ui-router` for states. and when user goes to the `Settings` link I need to upload from server tabs that user has access to.

My state provider

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "templates/home/index.html"
    })
    .state('settings', {
        url: "/settings",
        controller: "SettingsController",
        templateUrl: "templates/home/settings.html",
    })
    .state('settings.users', {
        url: "/users",
        controller: "SettingsUsersController",
        templateUrl: "templates/home/settings/users.html",
    })
    .state('settings.roles', {
        url: "/roles",
        controller: "SettingsRolesController",
        templateUrl: "templates/home/settings/roles.html",
    });
```

`SettingsController` looks like this:

```
app.controller('SettingsController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.tabs = [];

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/menu/get'
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.tabs = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            window.location = '/auth/login';
        });
    }
]);
```

Sample server answer

```
[{
    "url": "settings.users",
    "title": "Users"
}, {
    "url": "settings.roles",
    "title": "Roles"
}]
```

My `settings.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: $first}">
      <a href="{{tab.url}}">{{tab.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to load first tab on `$http` end in `SettingsController`, also to connect it to corresponding Controller? And how to switch active tab on different states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it is possible to define routes dynamically, but you could achieve your targets the following way.

1. Define all possible routes of your app.
2. Make them inaccessible for user without certain permissions (i use
   [this approach](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/4e927af3a15f)).
3. Load user's permissions.
4. Build tabs from those permissions (don't show nav before this
   point).

Additionally, it's worth checking on server side if user has permissions to page when he tries to load it. Because he can look at code and to try to access it bypassing the navigation.

Comment: My problem is not Auth, server is responding with states, that are allowed to user (as in my example of JSON). What I am trying to achieve is to set first tab active, load it's content and if I have another tab's url - make it active and load corresponding data.

Comment: You can set first tab active by: 1) inject $state into your app.run() and assign it to the $rootScope: `app.run(function($rootScope, $state, ...){ $rootScope.$state = $state; })` to make it available in controllers via $scope. 2) inside your success callback make `.success(function(data){ $scope.tabs = data; $scope.$state.go($scope.tabs[0].url); })`. Content of this state will be loaded inside it's controller or via 'resolve' property of ui-router state.

Comment: About another tabs - you want to preload their data or what?

Comment: Thank you, its something what i wanted. 

When application runs and I click at `/settings` link at first it redirects me to the `/settings/users`, but if I click one again at `/settings`, `SettingController` doesn't redirects to the `/settings/users`. How to achieve that behavior? 

Another question: my `templates/home/settings/users.html` in `SettingsUsersController` doesn't loads anywhere, why?

Comment: Could you make jsfiddle example? It's not so obvious only in words.